# Running Python scripts in Chrome on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, python, google-chrome-extensions, python3

I would like to run Python scripts (.py files) in Windows 7 Enterprise WITHOUT downloading anything, since I am at a school library. After some research, I found some Chrome apps that CAN run Python, such as [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/skulpt-interpreter/bocjplmmdjglmffmpofmmndklbdpcmeb?hl=en) and [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python/nodpmmidbgeganfponihbgmfcoiibffi?hl=en), however you can't actually save/open your work to a PY file. I also found Python Editor v4 beta (see below link), which would be perfect if it didn't refuse to open files.

Is there any way I can run .py files without downloading anything, or is it not possible?

```
chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python-editor-v4-beta/lldlpeacadpdfaoekhaiphamkndjghgo?hl=en
```

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, I actually managed to do it! Here's how:

- I went to the Microsoft Virtual Labs for Windows Server 2012 and clicked the Web Client.
- In the client, I went ahead and ran the Python 3.4.3 installer.
- After it finished installing, I went to the directory where I installed it (Python34) and zipped it.
- I went to a file upload site (Gmail was blocked, too big for Evernote, first 2 file sites were blocked) and uploaded it.
- Back in the school computer (exiting the client), I extracted the contents.
- Using a 'hack' (in a sense) to run CMD (hint: use a .BAT file), I ran `set PATH = %PATH%;C:\...\Python34`.
- `python` runs Python.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use: https://colab.research.google.com/, It needs a Google account.

Also you can save files.